# Why $line = fgets("data/$f_handle") does not work

Tags: php, fgets

Okay, the situation looks simple enough, so what am I doing wrong?

```
$fname = "students.dat";
$f_handle = fopen("data/$fname", 'r');
$num_lines = count(file("data/$fname"));
for($x=0; $x<$num_lines; $x++) {
    $line = fgets("data/$f_handle");
    echo "Line $x: ($line)<br />"; //exit;
    if(strpos($line,$studentID)) {
    // Line has studentID
    echo "Line $x: ($line)($studentID)<br /> <br />";
    // Exit the loop if found
    break;      
}
```

My output is this:

```
Line 0: ()
Line 1: ()
Line 2: ()
Line 3: ()
Line 4: ()
Line 5: ()
```

I went flat-file, because my MySQL attempts were/are failing, $studentID is correct, and there are six lines to the data file.  Any advice, please?

Answer (score 2):

`$f_handle` contains a resource object (a handle to the file you've just opened). Interpolating that in a string, as in `"data/$f_handle"` makes no sense. Just use `fgets($f_handle)` instead.

Apart from that though, there are several other problems in your code:

- Counting the number of lines separately like you do is not the most useful approach, as it requires reading the file twice. Instead, use something like `$x = 0; while(($line = fgets($f_handle)) !== false) { ... ; $x++; }` instead.
- `strpos()` returns `false` if there's no match, but it also returns `0` if the needle substring if found at the beginning of the haystack string. Both behave as `false` in an `if` condition. You should compare against `false` directly instead: `if(strpos(...) !== false)`.
- However, `strpos()` will likely not work here either. Imagine you're searching for a student with the ID `10`, but the current line you're scanning has the ID `102`. Your test will wrongly match on that line.
- There is an opening brace after the `if()`, but no matching closing brace.